# Is it possible to provision the host itself with docker-machine?

Tags: docker, docker-machine

Is it possible to provision the host itself with docker-machine for example with?

```
 docker-machine create \
 --driver generic \
 --generic-ip-address=localhost \
 --generic-ssh-key ~/.ssh/id_rsa \
 --generic-ssh-user root \
vm2
```

It seems that is doesn't work with this command.

Answer (score -1):

I have got this working using the procedure here(https://sreeninet.wordpress.com/2015/05/31/docker-machine/). Look under this section "Native hosts(Update as of March 23, 2016):". The steps needs to be exactly followed as it took some time for me to get it right...

Comment: With other hosts than the one running docker-machine it works fine with the generic driver. only my localhost doesn't work